# Can't enable Windows XP file sharing

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, service

The "sharing and security" option in the right-click context menu on a folder is no longer there.  The File and Print sharing option is "installed" and turned on in the TCP/IP properties, but the ability to share any folders has disappeared, along with all previously shared folders.  Where should I check to see what the issue is here?

**EDIT** From comments below:

"Server" service is not starting, see comment below for more... Firewall is completely disabled, too.

This is XP Pro, Simple File Sharing is turned on. We've discovered that the "Server" Windows service is not starting on bootup for some reason. When attempting manual start, we get "error 2001: specified driver is invalid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got it solved.  I found information claiming that this was related to a missing or corrupt "srv.sys" driver in c:\windows\system32\drivers.  When I looked there on the fouled up machine, that file was completely missing.  I copied the file from another working XP Pro machine, rebooted the problem machine, and sharing works once again.  Thanks for the help, folks!

Comment: Hey, good deal.  Thanks for posting the follow-up!

Answer (score 3):

If this is Windows XP Home, you won't be able to see that context menu without some registry hacking.  If this is Windows XP Professional, you might need to disable Simple File Sharing.  In a Windows Explorer windows, go to Tools --> Folder Options.  Click on the "View" tab and scroll all the way down.  Uncheck the box that says "Use simple file sharing."

Answer (score 1):

In windows explorer : Alt + T ( Tools menu ) - View - last option in the list is "Use simple file sharing" 
Uncheck that option and Sharing and Security will be shown.

Oh, and yes, as rawarren said, if you have Windows XP home edition sharing and security is not an option :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the drive you're trying to share formatted as NTFS?

Do you have simple file sharing turned on?  In Windows Explorer, Pick "Folder Options" from the Tools menu, click the View tab and look for "Use simple file sharing" in the Advanced Settings list.  Turn it off if it's selected.

If you have XP Home, you won't see this option in the list, you'll have to edit the registry.  In Regedit, look for the key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Delete the key nNamed  Nosecuritytab  or change the value to 0.

Check that the Computer Browser service is running, if it's not, check the services it's dependent on (Server and Workstation - see Dependencies tab).  If the services won't start, I'd start to wonder if there's a corrupt file.  Run the System File Checker:

Sfc /Scannow

You may need the install CD, or sfc will look in %Systemroot%\System32\Dllcache

Comment: This is XP Pro, Simple File Sharing is turned on.  We've discovered that the "Server" Windows service is not starting on bootup for some reason.  When attempting manual start, we get "error 2001: specified driver is invalid."

Comment: What about the Computer Browser service?  If the server service isn't running, it shouldn't be either, but what's in the error log when you try to start that one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinXP Pro:

**Solution 1:** open Windows Explorer and choose Folder Options from the Tools menu, then under Advanced Settings uncheck "Use simple file sharing"

**Solution 2:** In the registry, change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\ForceGuest` to **0**

Answer (score -1):

Who cares about Windows XP file sharing.   I would recommend just using [HFS File server](http://www.dovedove.it/hfs/hfs260.exe).  Its way easier.

Comment: If you're not going to bother even attempting to answer the OP's question, then don't bother to post at all.

Answer (score -1):

Better Fix

click Start button
click Control panel
click administrative Tools
click services short cut
slide down to Server right click properties
set start up type to automatic

done finished

Comment: The question states that the Server service isn't starting, so setting it to Automatic wouldn't help.